# how to use specific element to drag component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, framer-motion

I'm building a drag and drop list with framer-motion and I have `motion.div` wrapper but I want a small handle inside this component to be able to use drag functionality.

Here's the example of code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-2-drag-to-reorder-forked-82nvd?file=/src/App.js

I want red box inside to use as a handle.

Comment: If you add screenshots of what the code does, as well as a working minimal example in something like codesandbox you'll get more help.

Comment: please add your code snippet.